# unordered_map for std::pair

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-pair

I want to create a map for std::pair object that will compare the object by the value of its fields.
I have implemented the following code after some research on stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer for what I was looking for.

I get a compilation error for the songHasher operator overloader but unsure if my implementation is the cause of it.

```
class song { ... };

struct songHasher {
    size_t operator()(std::pair<int, int> a) const noexcept {
        return (size_t) a.first ^ a.second;
    }
};

struct songComparator {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int> & a, const std::pair<int, int> &b) const {
        return a.first == b.first && a.second == b.seconds;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<
    std::pair<int, int>,
    song*,
    songHasher,
    songComparator> albumMap;
```

Thanks.

Comment: `b.seconds` doesn't make sense either; `b` has a `second` member, not a `seconds` member.

Comment: Please show the error message that you are getting. There is nothing wrong except for the `seconds` -> `second` typo.

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the bad naming. `songHasher` looks like it would hash a `song`, which would be the mapped value and thus wrong, but it actually does the correct thing and hashes the key. Same with `songComparator`.

Comment: Btw your comparator does not seem to be required since it does exactly what default std::pair comparator would do

Comment: the .seconds was a typo unrelevant to my actual code. @DenisSheremet Thanks then I'm done.